# How to map single file(.csv) column to multiple table columns using sqlldr

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a file(.csv) contains the columns A1,A2,A3 and Table has the columns T1,T2,T3,T4,T5.

I want to map or insert data from A2 column to T2,T3,T4.I am able to insert into 
T2 and T3 using desc_skip FILLER POSITION(1) in control file(.ctl) but not in T4.
Could you please help me How to insert single file column value into more than 
Two columns in table using sqlldr.

Please find the control file below which i am using.

```
LOAD DATA
INTO TABLE EMP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
    "T1" INTEGER ,
    "T2" CHAR,  
    desc_skip FILLER POSITION(1),
    "T3" CHAR,
    "T4" CHAR,
    "T5" INTEGER
)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want to populate the same value in three columns?  Or split the data in some way?

Comment: Yes want to populate same value in three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something similar to

```
...
T2 char,
T3 expression ":T2",
T4 expression ":T2",
...
```

P.S. I cannot imagine what can 'not working'. My example:

Database:

```
SQL> create table t$loader (t1 varchar2(10), t2 varchar2(10), t3 varchar2(10), t4 varchar2(10), t5 varchar2(10));

Table created
```

CSV file:

```
echo 1,2,3 > csv.csv
echo 4,5,6 >> csv.csv
echo 7,8,9 >> csv.csv
```

Control file:

```
load data
  infile 'csv.csv'
  into table t$loader
  fields terminated by ','
(
  t1 char,
  t2 char,
  t3 expression ":t2",
  t4 expression ":t2",
  t5 char
)
```

Run:

```
sqlldr userid=user/password@db control=csv.ctl
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from t$loader;

T1         T2         T3         T4         T5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1          2          2          2          3
4          5          5          5          6
7          8          8          8          9
```

Isn't it what you ask for?

Comment: Hi Sanders,Thank u for response. But it is not working.Could u please help me how to copy A2 column value to T2,T3,T4 columns by configuring in .ctl file.

Comment: Thanks Sanders. It's working now.Thank you very much

Comment: TRAILING NULLCOLS 
("T1" INTEGER EXTERNAL  NULLIF "T1"=BLANKS,
 "T2" CHAR  NULLIF "T2"=BLANKS,
 "T3" CHAR  NULLIF "T3"=BLANKS ":T2",
 "T4" INTEGER EXTERNAL  NULLIF "T4"=BLANKS,
 "T5" INTEGER EXTERNAL  NULLIF "T5"=BLANKS ":T4")  Hi Sanders , i am facing problem when using in java program, the sqlldr command is inserting upto T3 column only.copy option(":T2") working fine. It is skipping T4 and T5. Could you please help on this.

Comment: Maybe you should remove needless nullifs. If not, try to restore well-worked version, then repeat changes one by another and check when it stops working.